# If demi-humans age by leveling up, then can they die of old age?

Tags: the-rising-of-the-shield-hero

If demi-humans grow older by acquiring more levels or becoming stronger, then could higher level demi-humans die from old age? Or is there an internal aging system that does not affect physical appearances?

Answer (score 1):

Demi humans only use the level to age method until they become adults then it's just normal age growth.

Comment: 'One-line' answers are discouraged. Please elaborate on your answer and include sources and evidences to support your claims.

Comment: Assuming you are correct (although supporting evidence would be required), theoretically someone could live forever if they never level up to the point of becoming an adult. That doesn't seem quite plausible.

Comment: Basically, they will level up naturally through just living, levelling up by acquiring exp simply makes this process faster. By the time they are adults (wether through age or level-up), the only way to gain levels is through EXP farming, but it doesn't affect maturity.